# Computing the limit of a function repeatedly composed with itself ($f_{n+1}(x) = f(f_n(x))$) such that $0 < f(x) < x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $(0,1)$ and suppose $0 < f(x) < x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Define $f_n(x)$ inductively by $f_1(x) = f(x)$, $f_{n+1}(x) = f(f_n(x))$. I am asked to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists and to compute it.

I observe that for any $x$, $\{f_n(x)\}$ is strictly decreasing, as well as that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is bounded below by $0$. So I say that the limit exists and is $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \inf\{f_n(x)\}$. However, I am not entirely sure how to properly approach computing the limit.

I would like to say that as $n$ increases, $f_n$ maps $(0,a)$ (where $a < 1$) to $(0,a-\epsilon)$, that is, $f_n$ maps intervals to increasingly smaller intervals that get smaller from the right, and that if you take the intersection of this infinite collection of images, you just end up with $\{0\}$. But I'm not entirely sure if that argument is correct--it seems a bit handwavy to me. What to do?

Comment: observe that the limit must be in $[0,1]$. then argue it can't be any number in $(0,1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ is also $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n+1}(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(f_n(x))$. If you could invert the limit and the composition by $f$, this would yield $L=f\left( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\right)=f(L)$.

Hence your task is two-fold: conclude that $L=$ $____$ from the identity $L=f(L)$, and prove that the interversion of $f$ and of the limit, used to reach the identity $L=f(L)$, is indeed legal.